# Emacs Style "artist-mode" for Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Is there anything that resembles [Emacs' artist mode](http://www.cinsk.org/emacs/emacs-artist.html) available for Eclipse?

Answer (score 1):

Not in as such.  But that demo almost makes me want to switch from vim!  Almost.

In the meantime, you can get some of that functionality in Eclipse from [FIGLet](http://www.jave.de/eclipse/figlet/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try Markus Gebhard's [JavE](http://www.jave.de/).

[image]

*Not really Eclipse, but...
..at least it is standalone java-application, so should be easy to copy-paste...*

Comment: Someone should make an Eclipse plugin out of this one.